# Prove that we have at least $n$ intersections

Tags: combinatorics

We have drawn $n$ circles with same radius that each two of them intersect at two points.Prove that we have at least $n$ intersections.

I tried induction and I think I solved it right but I need a proof using double counting.I think we should pay attention to intersection points I did like below:

consider we have intersection points $A_1,A_2,\dots ,A_M$ and we define $a_i$ to be the number of circle that contain $A_i$ we draw a $m*n$ chart and if the circle $j$ contains $A_i$ we put $\frac{1}{a_i}$ at the $j$th column and $i$th row so the sum of the numbers in the chart is $m$(using rows) so we only need to prove the sum of the numbers is at least $n$ but I can't do that.

Comment: I do not quite understand your first sentence. Could you clarify?

Comment: @DreamConspiracy It was incomplete I think I forgot them while typing now I fixed that.

Comment: You likely mean to count the intersections without regard to multiplicity.  It is possible for a point of intersection to belong to more than one circle (of equal radius).  It would improve the Question to clarify this, one way or the other.  Also, an example where exactly $n$ intersections are attained might be helpful to Readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By assumption, each pair of circles determines two intersections $P,Q$ and a common chord $PQ.$ Because the circles all have equal radii, no chord can be shared by more than two circles; thus the $\binom n2$ pairs of circles determine $\binom n2$ distinct chords. On the other hand, since each chord joins two intersections, the number of chords is at most $\binom m2,$ where $m$ is the number of intersections. This shows that $\binom n2\le\binom m2.$ It follows that $n\le m,$ provided $n\ge2.$ In fact, the proposition is false for $n=1.$ Also, I tacitly assumed that the circles lie in a plane; the proposition is false for circles in space.